# why exporting an "HISTTIMEFORMAT" with a data saves into .bash_history timestamp?

Tags: bash

I've added in the bottom of my `.bash_profile` this line:

> export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y "

But the content of my history appears like

```
source .bash_profile
#1524222131
source .bash_profile
#1524222136
vim .bash_history i
#1524222151
rm .bash_history
#1524222152
vim .bash_history i
#1524222156
ll
#1524222158
vim .bash_history
#1524222163
ll
#1524226543
vim .bash_history
```

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation of `bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) says:

> **`HISTTIMEFORMAT`**
>
> If this variable is set and not null, its value is used as a format string for [`strftime(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) to print the time stamp associated with each history entry displayed by the `history` builtin. If this variable is set, time stamps are written to the history file so they may be preserved across shell sessions. This uses the history comment character to distinguish timestamps from other history lines.

In plain English, it's entirely up to `bash` how it saves the timestamps of the commands in `.bash_history`. The saving part cares only about the emptiness of `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` and not about its content.

The `history` command is the one that uses the value of `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` to format the timestamps.